# Snowflake and SAS Connect sql

Tags: sas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to know how to solve this error in the connection from SAS to snowflake. By direct ODBC it works. By SAS it gives me the error of:

> CLI prepare error: Cannot perform SELECT. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name.

Successful ODBC test in iODBC:
[image: Successful ODBC test in iODBC]

SAS Log messages:
[image: SAS Log messages]

Comment: Are you specifying a database in your connection string from SAS to Snowflake?  The issue you are seeing means you are not, or there is a typo.  I'd check that first.

Comment: Can you include your full connection string (as SAS code, so somethign like `libname whatever odbc (... ) ; `) in the text of your question?  Thanks, and welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL query Snowflake needs to know the database and schema for any table that you are referencing. You either need to include this information in your connection definition or in your SQL. If you are referencing tables in multiple DBs/Schemas then any not in the DB/Schema you include in the connection would need to be fully qualified.
Assuming your connection is just to your Snowflake account, with no DB/Schema information, then your SQL would need to look something like:

```
select count(*) from snow.db_name.schema_name.LA_DNA_PREPAD_BASE_SNAP
```

Answer (score 0):

In ODBC, you did this:

```
select * from **STRATA_DW**.LANDING.LA_DNA_PREPAID_BASE_SNAP;
```

In SAS you did this:

```
Select * from LANDING.LA_DNA_PREPAID_BASE_SNAP
```

Can you see the difference? You never referenced the database name in your SAS query...